# Including Jar from one project in a Git Repository to another project in a different Repository as a Maven Build

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I have a requirement I want in my eclipse to have a jar file of  say project 1 in Git Repository 1 in another project say project 2 which is in Git repository2. I am currently in Git Repository 2 and it has to be a maven build. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Is the JAR in repository 1 already built and checked into git as a .jar file that you want to include as a maven dependency of project 2? Or are you wanting to build the artifact from project 1 as part of the build for project 2?

Comment: I have a class which needs to be used in project 2 for project 1. But I have a maven build process which  builds all modules of project 2 first. Now in one of these modules I require that jar file to be available. how can this be done

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `Git`. If your have `Maven` build just run `mvn install` in project 1 which will install jar 1 to the local Maven repository. Then declare project 1 as dependency of project 2 like

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>your.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>projec-1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```